# PyQt5 terminate application from worker

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

This is an example of the application that starts the `QApp -> Worker -> Something that causes sys.exit() inside the worker`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRunnable, pyqtSlot, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        worker = Worker()
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setFixedSize(600, 300)
        self.show()


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        print("Running worker...")
        run_application()


def run_window():
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


def run_application():
    print('Running application...')
    sys.exit(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_window()
```

There are several cases when I run it:
exits with code 0
exits with code 10
window keeps hanging

It feels like a racing.
So what is the correct way to terminate the window in case of the `sys.exit()` or the exception inside the worker?

**Edit**: forgot to mention that I need to return the exit code and track it since I run the window through the `subprocess/Popen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to close the windows then a possible solution is to terminate the eventloop using [`QCoreApplication::quit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit):

```py
def run_application():
    print("Running application...")
    QCoreApplication.quit()
```

Or [`QCoreApplication::exit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit):

```py
def run_application():
    print("Running application...")
    QCoreApplication.exit(10)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I need to return the exit code and track it since I run the window through the subprocess/Popen.

Comment: Seems that the `QCoreApplication.exit(10)` works. Thank you very much. By the way had one of the ways as calling the application inside the try-catch to catch the sys.exit and then to throw the worker.signal into the window and then to do the sys.exit again.